# Updated all values in a pandas dataframe based on all instances of a specific value in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My apologies beforehand! I have done this before a few times, but I am having some brain fog. I have two dataframes df1, and df2. I would like to update all values in df2 if it matches a specific value in df1, while not changing the other values in df2. I can do this pretty easily with `np.where` on columns of a dataframe, I am having brain fog on how I did this previously with 2 dataframes!

Goal: Set values in Df2 to 0 if they are 0 in DF1 - otherwise keep the DF2 value

Example

**df1**

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 |

**df2**

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 | 7 |
| 1 | 4 | 6 |

**Expected df2 after our element swap**

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 |

brain fog is bad! thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `fillna`

```
>>> df2[df1 != 0].fillna(0)
```

Comment: thank you rafaelc! I think this did the trick. its so funny to forget about fillna...or many other helpful funcntions...especially close to the weekend! lol. I will verify my results fully and report back

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```py
df2[df1.eq(0)] = 0
```

```
print(df2)

   A  B  C
0  1  0  1
1  0  2  0
2  1  4  0
```

Comment: Hi Ynjxsjmh I tried this already, but I think I need to initiate a loop for all entries, or the use the apply function. I will try it again, but as I recall my results were not right. I will report back

Comment: @HarisJaved You can post the samples where the result is not right.